# Passing a total between groups in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum, subtotal

Group 1 = Date of order

Group 2 = product and current on hand

Day1

```
20140423   (Day 1)   
product A                   200    
Order 1                     -20
Order 2                     -20
Balance                     160

Product B                   100
Order 1                     - 5
```

Day 2

```
20140424  (Day 2)
Product C                    16
Order 1                     - 5
```

Day 3

```
20140425  (Day 3)
Product A                   160
```

How do I pass the ending balance from `Product A day 1` to the beginning balance for `Product A day 3`

Pls explain in detail because I am a novice report writer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach:
Create a formula `@StoreValue` and write below code.

```
    Local NumberVar Storevalue;
    Local NumberVar display;

    if ({Date},{@Group1})=20140423 and ({Product},{@Group2})=product A'
    Then Storevalue:=//Balance value of A;

    if ({Date},{@Group1})=20140425 and ({Product},{@Group2})=product A'
        Then display:=Storevalue;
    else 
    display:=//Your calculation here;
    display;
```

Now place this value in `Balance` row.